# How do I tell what is filling up the transaction log?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

We have a transaction log on a sql database and for some reason it has filled up to 50GB when our live system only has about 2GB. Is there any way I can profile sql or the transaction log to try and find out why this particular one has grown so much?

Comment: What recovery model are you using? Full..simple? Do you create Transaction Log Backups or only Full Backups? If you don't know the answer to these, I suppose it's yes to both, so you should first follow Remus's advice.

Answer (score 5):

Start by investigating what is holding up the log reuse. Read [Factors That Can Delay Log Truncation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345414%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), look at `log_reuse_wait_desc value` is [`sys.databases`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx). Based on what you find there, there could be several potential actions.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that you are not backing up the transaction log. This is not the same thing as backing up the database. I would suggest you back it up at least daily. In a high transaction environment, it should be backed up more frequently, ours is backed up every 15 minutes.